# In theme development, are there functions which write HTML in a standard fashion to reduce "spaghetti code"?

Tags: theme-development

For example, if I'm building a list in a plugin that loops over an array to produce a list `ul` or `ol`. I typically see code as follows.

```
foreach($list as $item) {
  $output .= '<li>' . $item['value'] . '</li>';
}
```

I guess I'm looking to see if there is a comparable to such functions in the Drupal world such as `theme_list()` ([reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7.x)). I'm looking to give my list of items to a function and have it write the HTML block in a standardized way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are specific functions like [`wp_list_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) and [`wp_list_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pages/) along with [some others](https://developer.wordpress.org/?s=wp_list&post_type%5B%5D=wp-parser-function) which will do this for you but for arbitrary arrays, WordPress doesn't have a function to neatly print it out into HTML for you. You could simply write your own functions for this purpose if you really need to I guess.

Answer (score 2):

For tree-like structures (e.g. nested lists) you can extend the `Walker` class: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker